# Photos on website only showing in one row, I need to add multiple rows

Tags: html, css

Why is my code displaying multiple rows instead of 1?

I can upload any number of photos to my site, but it only displays 4 photos across, the 4 most recently uploaded, on the website. I want it to display 4 rows of photos, instead of 1 row.

```
<div class="profile_box_body">
            <?php
            if(!empty($RecentPhotos)){
            ?>
            <div class="profile_photos_list row">
                <?php
                foreach($RecentPhotos as $value){ ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 media_item block-center">
                        <div class="profile_photo ">
                            <!--<a href="javascript:void();" class="clickable"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">-->
                            <a href="<?=WATERMARK_FILE!=''?DisplayImageWithWatermark($value):DB_DOMAIN.'uploads/images/'. $value['bigimage']; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery<?php echo $value["aid"] ?>" >
                                <div class="img-container-large">
                                    <div class="img-responsive-container img-responsive-container--border">
                                        <img src="<?=$value['image']; ?>" class="pImageBorder img-responsive-container__img">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="pImageUsername"><b><?=$value['title']; ?></b><br/><?=$value['description']; ?></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            else {
            ?>
                <a class="" style="float: none; text-align: center" href='<?=getThePermalink('account/&dll=gallery')?>'><p> <?=$lang_register_page['a14'] ?></p></a>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some of your output's screenshots into your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your HTML or CSS. The problem is into your PHP query. You should check first that, is there a **limit = 1** called into your query?